# Everything stopped working after changing icon themes

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, crash, gnome-tweaks

Ubuntu 22.04.
I had an error after changing an icon theme theme this time through tweaks, then I observed that everything, literally everything stopped working. Only browsers would open.
**Thnx** in advance.

Comment: More info needed. Changed to what theme? How did you change the theme? What was the error or errors? Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes. I changed to whitesur-icon-theme 
GitHub link: (https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-icon-theme)
I've done it a couple of times before, It worked properly, and I think it's not a specific issue on this theme.. I've applied this using Gnome tweaks. Thnx.